# How to link a history table to the parent table

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, entity-relationship

Parent table is OBJECT.

Child table is OBJECT_STATUS_HISTORY.

One OBJECT has many OBJECT_STATUS_HISTORY's.

For the current OBJECT's status only the last OBJECT_STATUS_HISTORY is relevant.

Can I map these two tables as they are and get NHibernate doing mapping OBJECT to OBJECT_STATUS_HISTORY but! having only the last record accessible. Basically can you restrict one_to_many mapping to one_to_one by some condition? The OBJECT_STATUS_HISTORY would remain a bag or set or a list with only one object, or one object itself, it is not that important.

It is a legacy database and this pattern is all around, since the database is receiving a historical input from outside, and no I cannot create a flag in OBJECT table that would give me a current status and then map it directly to NHibernate.

Of course, I can add to OBJECT memory class the status from OBJECT_STATUS_HISTORY later, but the question is: can I do this only using the mapping? I can easily create an SQL statement for this object, so in essence I can create a view with the above requirement and then map it in NHibernate, but can NHibernate do this on its own?

Let me now if the question was not clear enough.

Comment: So you are looking to add a filter on the `bag` or `set` that retrieves the latest `object_status_history` for an `order`?

Comment: Yes. It seems to me that this is not possible in some general sense. It is possible to return something last, like ID with latest date. Essentially the question is: can you filter 0-to-many somehow to get 0-to-1 by some condition.

Answer (score 1):

In TSQL i would use top to only get one record, and in the query do an order by so that you always get the newest record.

```
select top 1 * from table_name
```

Comment: Sure, this is a solution regarding SQL itself, but what to do with NHibernate, how to link it to have it as an object.